# What are assembly references for GetValue/SetValue for creating DependancyProperty

Tags: silverlight

I have a hard time setting up a Silverlight Class Library project.   In this project, I am trying to create a dependancy property.  The code requires to use SetValue and GetValue methods -- the project cannot resolve these methods.  What do I need to reference to access these methods?  Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to derive the class, which implements the dependancy property, from the "Control" base class.  The reference to SetValue and GetValue methods now appear to be resolved.

public class ClassName: Control
{
   ...
}